# Object $("#elementID") has no method when called as STRING

Tags: jquery, variables, object, element, offset

Got a problem here. Been searching on Google and the website for a few hours, but can't find the solution.

**The problem**

I've got 3 variables, which store *classes, sections or ids*. I bundle them together like below:

```
var clickedElement = '$("' + headParentID + parentClass + ' ' + thisNodeName + '")';
```

The value of **clickedElement** is the following:

```
$("#navigation .logo img")
```

The next step is to find the x coordinates of this 'element' using the following code:

```
var x = clickedElement.offset().left;
```

And here comes the problem. I'm getting the following error in the console logs:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Object $("#navigation .logo.six.columns img") has no method 'offset'**

But when I use the output of **clickedElement** and put it in the code like the example below, **it does give me the x coordinates..**

```
var x = $("#navigation .logo img").offset().left;
```

Any jQuery/Javascript hero around that can solve this mystery? It would mean a lot!

Thanks!

Comment: Your `clickedElement` is a string.

Comment: I think `var clickedElement = '$("' + headParentID + parentClass + ' ' + thisNodeName + '")';` should be `var clickedElement = $(headParentID + parentClass + ' ' + thisNodeName);`

Comment: Why on earth are you setting it as string???

Comment: Thanks guys! Very stupid of not seeing I was setting it as a string.. Feeling a bit dumb now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing here is *not actually generating a jQuery object*. You are actually just concatenating a string:

```
var clickedElement = '$("' + headParentID + parentClass + ' ' + thisNodeName + '")';
// result (note the quotes surrounding the object: 
// clickedElement = '$("#navigation .logo img")'
```

What you want to do is something like this:

```
var clickedElement = $( headParentID + parentClass + ' ' + thisNodeName );
// result: clickedElement = $("#navigation .logo img")
```

The error you are getting is basically saying that a string object does not have the `offset()` method.

Comment: Well, I feel quite stupid now.. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @DannyPostma - naaa, don't feel bad :) It happens to the best of us (hazards of working late nights). Glad to help - happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You are actually searching for a method `.offset()` over a string.

Try,

```
var clickedElement = $(headParentID + parentClass + " " + thisNodeName);
var x = clickedElement.offset().left;
```